# Rails request.headers data not updating without refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-headers, turbolinks

When I hit site for first time, then results of `request.headers[HTTP_ACCEPT]` is `"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"`

but between internal links requests it shows `text/html, application/xhtml+xml`
until I hard refresh the page.

Is it due to turbolinks or any other issue?

Comment: You show far too few informations for anyone to be able to give you a reasonable answer. Depending on your setup, you might try to remove turbolinks to see if it comes from it. Also, is there anything not working because of this issue?

Comment: yes I can't access webp support headers

Comment: What is the actual action you are trying to do that fails? Are you trying to download an image, for example? What is the absence of those headers making impossible?

Comment: No basically I am trying to check either browser supports webp image format or not....

Comment: Try to actually serve an image and include it as an image in an HTML page. If turbolinks has an effect on requests for HTML, it should not have an effect on requests that the browser does to fetch images.

Answer (score 0):

It's a turbolinks issue. By default, the turbolinks' XMLHttpRequest, only send the headers "text/html, application/xhtml+xml", but you can send the "image/webp" header by capturing the request-start event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:request-start", function(event) {
  var xhr = event.data.xhr
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "image/webp")
})
```

The question is how to know from javascript whether or not the browser accepts webp images to send the "image/webp" header to the server.

You can use the Modernize library or a custom function that guess if webp is available when trying to decode a small webp image like described here: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq. However, these solutions add a certain overhead that precludes the benefit of the fastest load time of webp images.

Maybe, the most efficient solution is to create a boolean cookie in the server side to store whether or not webp images are accepted. The cookie is stored with the first browser GET call to the server. In subsequent turbolinks calls you can check this cookie in your javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:request-start", function(event) {
  browserAcceptsWebp = document.cookie.includes('webp_available=true');
  if (browserAcceptsWebp) {
    var xhr = event.data.xhr;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "image/webp");
  }
});
```